# Can we say 'nonstop' to mean without resting along the road while traveling?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

We went on a road trip to Moskow from Vladivostok (a city in Russia). We had some stops to sleep, rest, or enjoy the scenery on the way to Moscow but we had to come back *without any stop* except for filling up the tank.

Can I use *nonstop* for the italic part above? I feel *nonstop* implies a repetitive action like *we keep coming back from our trip* which doesn't make sense. Am I right?

Informal words or phrases are also welcome. Plus if there is a word or phrase that shows disapproval or humor that is it's not normal to do so please mention that, too.

Thanks

[Edit: Thanks to JavaLatte's comment, I changed the spelling of "non stop" to "nonstop"]

Comment: You can also say "We drove straight through." which also implies no detours or side trips.

Comment: I think "nonstop" implies no stops at all, not even for petrol, and "nonstop except"..." sounds wrong. I'd say "...but on the way back we weren't able to stop except to fill up the tank."

Comment: nonstop, non-stop or non stop? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300315/nonstop-non-stop-or-non-stop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On the way back we drove nonstop except for petrol/gas.

definition:

> nonstop
>
> (Of a passenger vehicle or journey) not having or making stops at intermediate places on the way to its destination

([Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nonstop))

Answer (score 1):

I think "nonstop" sounds OK (it's one word). You could also say "without stopping".

That's a hell of a road trip.